# calculate between two dates in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to calculate between two dates.

```
create table greatestdate(name varchar(20),city varchar(20),current_dates varchar(12),previous_date varchar(12));// create table



insert into greatestdate values('samuel','newyork','02-04-2013','01-01-2013'); //insert values

select * from greatestdate where (current_dates -previous_date)> 2 months as result;
```

however iam getting syntax error. kindly please any one suggest me.

i tried this code,

```
select * from greatestdates where (now() -  previous_date) < interval '2 month';
```

getting error message as,

ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer < interval
LINE 1: ...atestdates where (current_dates -  previous_date) < interval...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

i am using postgresql 9.2 version,

Comment: If you are asking a PostgreSQL question, please don't apply tags for other databases.  If you intend to ask something that is relevant to SQL Server and/or Oracle, please edit your question to show how it is relevant to those databases.

Comment: "I am getting syntax error". What error *exactly*? At what statement? What PostgreSQL version? **Always show the exact text of error messages**.

Comment: Also, is this homework?

Answer (score 2):

The full error is:

```
regress=> select * from greatestdate where (current_dates -previous_date)> 2 months as result;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "months"
LINE 1: ...atestdate where (current_dates -previous_date)> 2 months as ...
                                                             ^
```

The problem is that you've written:

```
2 months
```

where you should write:

```
INTERVAL '2' MONTH
```

or:

```
CAST('2 months' AS interval)
```

See the syntax for intervals in the user manual.

Once you fix that you'll find another problem - you're trying to apply an `as` alias to a `WHERE` clause. That's nonsensical. Delete `as result` entirely.

This will reveal a third problem: You're trying to subtract two `varchar` columns. This doesn't make sense and won't work. Fix your schema to use `date`, `timestamp without time zone` or `timestamp with time zone` for the date fields instead of storing them as `varchar`. Once your table definition is fixed the statement should finally work. Storing dates as `varchar` is never a good idea.

In future please show your PostgreSQL version and the exact text of the error message in all questions.

Comment: however i tried this code and using posgresql 9.2 version

   select * from greatestdate where (current_dates -previous_date) < CAST('2 month' AS interval);

getting error message as and i have changed as well as data type,

ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying - character varying
LINE 1: select * from greatestdate where (current_dates -previous_da...
                                                        ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: i changed datatype as date instead of varchar

Comment: @Patrick Please edit your question to add the new code and new error message. Don't replace the old one, just add the new stuff to the end. It's hard to see what's going on in comments where there's no formatting. Comment here when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

This last error, after extensive error tracking by @Craig,

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: integer < interval LINE 1: 
...atestdates where (current_dates - previous_date) < interval... 
^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). 
You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

happens because the date type arithmetic returns integer, not interval. To avoid that:

```
select *
from greatestdates
where current_dates - interval '2 month' > previous_date;
```

Comment: i got an answer for this query was used,select * from greatestdates where (now() - previous_date)  between  interval '0 month' and '2 months';it is working very fine.